# How to set up navigation properties in Moq?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, c#-4.0, moq

I am not able to access a property of a navigation object of an entity in EF, hence my unit test is failing again and again.

Comment: I am sorry, but from the description it is very unclear what you are going to achieve. Some code example could be helpful :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I had some other errors which led to this issue, however resolved now.